# Cassandra Cluster Incremental Backup to s3

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cassandra, database-backups

We've setup a Cassandra cluster with three nodes in a single Available zone(AWS). We're using nodetool snapshot tool to take the backup to S3 storage.

Initially, we're planning to take full backup and then enable incremental backup and periodically move the backup to S3.

It wouldn't be of great help if anyone could please provide a script which can take incremental backup and move the backups to S3.

Comment: did you check tablesnap? https://github.com/JeremyGrosser/tablesnap

Comment: We're using nodetool snapshot because we've already verified backup & restore manually using nodetool but tablesnap script uses inotify. :(

Comment: OpsCenter does it if you have DSE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are tools such as Netflix Priam which can take backups on AWS

Comment: I agree but Netflix Priam doesn't work with Latest versions. We're using nodetool snapshot for backing up